# How to translate string on mobile menu?

Tags: magento2, menu, mobile, translate

Simple question, how to translate string "settings" on mobile menu?

[image]

Comment: Have you added a translated string in `csv` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your **csv** file (I have add translated text for italian)

```
"Settings","impostazioni"
```

Copy file from below path

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml

And past into your theme directory.

> app/design/frontend/Themefolder/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml

And change code from `<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?>` To `<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($label); ?>`

If you want to translate string in .html file then you have to use `<?php echo __('your string'); ?>`

[Fore more refrance check this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Worked just this --> "Settings","impostazioni" thank you

Comment: You are welcome :)